# Beautiful soup - capture all links with a certain class or text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to capture all the relevant links from a web page with beautiful soup. All the links I need have both the `class="btn btn-gray"` and also the text `<a...>More Info<>`

What's the best way to extract just these links?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

all_links = []
links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['btn', 'btn-gray']})
for link in links:
    if 'More Info' in link.text:
        all_links.append(link['href'])  # Save href only, for example.
```

or as a clean list comprehension:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': ['btn', 'btn-gray']})
results = [link['href'] for link in links if 'More Info' in link.text]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
buttons = soup.findAll('a', {'class': ['btn', 'btn-gray']})

links = [link for link in buttons if "More Info" in link.text]
```